# Python memory leak when converting and saving numpy array as image

Tags: python, memory, numpy, memory-leaks

I have a simple setup:

Producer reads a set of images from a camera, and concatenates them using numpy.row_stack(). The produced array is put into Queue.Queue.

Consumer constantly waits for data using Queue.get() and as soon as it receives data it saves the images to a file. For whatever reason the process leaks memory like there is no tomorrow. <strike>If I don't put images into the thread queue no leaking occurs.
Apparently it is NOT the queue that is leaking, but something in my save image function. Specifically it is in the creating the temporary file part.</strike> Here is the implementation:

```
def _createTmpFile(self, image):
    filename = '/tmp/imgTemp.gray'
    with open(filename, 'wb') as fp: 
        scaled  = image * 16
        big     = numpy.asmatrix(scaled, dtype='>i2')
        fp.write(big.tostring())
    return filename

def _saveImage(self, filename, image):
    tmpFile = self._createTmpFile(image)
    try:
        # Call a blocking sub process command to convert the image:
        command = ('convert -size %dx%d -depth 16 -endian MSB' % ( image.shape[1], image.shape[0])).split(' ')
        command += [tmpFile, '/tmp/' + os.path.basename(filename)]
        log.debug("command being called: %s" % str(command))
        subprocess.call(command)
        os.unlink(tmpFile)
        log.info("Image %s is saved." % filename)
    except Exception as e:
        log.exception()
        log.warning("Failed to save image %s" % filename)
```

I don't see anything particular standing out to me, which would cause a memory leak. Any ideas?

UPDATE: After a thorough analysis the problem turned out be pretty simple - producer was creating images at a much faster rate than consumer could save them, thus filling up the queue. When I would cancel the request for images I would drain the queue, but it seems like the GC was not quick enough to pick up the multitude of images, so they were clogging up the memory.

Comment: Can you strip your program down to the minimum amount of code that runs and triggers the problem, then post that?

Answer (score 0):

the subprocess.call() is the reason, you should put a wait or so command in there, and/or to let it go in a new terminal or so, with some kwarg. Since otherwise it starts up the call, and than later in the queue it does something similar, (using commandline things is tricky with subprocess)

i think check_call() with shell=True should work, instead of the subprocess.call, but i am not entirely sure of that either. I had a similar problem once, and i think that solved it

Another reason might be that in your queue, if you call multiple times the createTmpFile, you write to the same temporary image, so multiple images are written over each other etc? that could cause a memoryleak i guess

Comment: No, unfortunately this didn't work. The leak occurs when I just create the temporary file, and don't call subprocess.call.

Comment: Yes, thanks for trying to help. I still have a little bit of a mystery why GC didn't clean up the non-referenced images.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes i just put a del x after some statement when i think it takes a lot of ram, or when it gets called a lot, just as a "just-in-case"-thing, to make stuff more idiotproof, since i know who uses the code later (self ;-) )